# Is it possible to bulk create folders in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, folder

My company sends multiple marketing emails per day, and as a result we like to organize our campaigns into daily folders. However - we currently create all of these folders manually, and it's a very manual and time-consuming process.

As an example, our current folder structure looks like this:

Email->Content

Content Builder

Campaigns

Promotional

[year] (2022, 2023, etc)

[##_Month] (01_January, 02_February, etc)

[yyyymmdd] (there are 28 of these for February, starting with 20230201 to 20230228; these are the "daily folders")

We also do the same thing (same folder structure) for Automations (my automations/Campaigns/Promotional/etc) and "Send Email" Activities (User-Initiated/Campaigns/Promotional/etc) in Automation Studio as well - so currently we need to create these folders 3x. What I want to do is to be able to bulk create all of the daily folders each month. Is that possible within SFMC Automation Studio?

I have limited experience with coding, so I would appreciate if the solution could be as simple as possible.

Thank you for your help.

Edit:
I've tried to use some SSJS scripts, but unfortunately they gave me an error. So far it's just telling me that the script failed to run with no other info, but I'm unable to find a log or a more specific error message. If someone knows how to access an error log (if one exists), I'd also appreciate it.

Here's the script I tried

```
<script runat="server">
var year = 2023;
var month = 3;
var monthName = new Date(year, month - 1, 1).toLocaleString('default', {
  month: 'long'
});
var monthStr = month < 10 ? "0" + month : month;
var folderPrefix = year + monthStr;
var folderName = "";
var parentFolder = "03_March";
var grandparentFolder = year;

var parentFolderObj = Folder.Retrieve({
  Property: "CustomerKey",
  SimpleOperator: "equals",
  Value: parentFolder
});

var grandparentFolderObj = Folder.Retrieve({
  Property: "CustomerKey",
  SimpleOperator: "equals",
  Value: grandparentFolder
});

var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

for (var day = 1; day <= lastDayOfMonth; day++) {
  var dayStr = day < 10 ? "0" + day : day;
  folderName = folderPrefix + dayStr;
  var newFolder = {
    Name: folderName,
    ContentType: "folder",
    CustomerKey: folderName,
    ParentFolder: {
      ID: parentFolderObj.ID
    }
  };
  parentFolderObj = Folder.Add(newFolder);
  parentFolderObj.ParentFolder = {
    ID: grandparentFolderObj.ID
  };
  Folder.Update(parentFolderObj);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am curious why this has been downvoted so much? It seems like a fair question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible.  I'd suggest working primarily with the Folder IDs not the names.  The names are ambiguous beneath the base folders, but the IDs are not.

Here's an example that will create year and month folders based on the base folder info.  You should be able to adapt this to suit your needs.

As for the folders for other objects besides Data Extensions, you can find a list of valid contentTypes [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/datafolder.html#content-types-for-child-folders).

```javascript
<script runat="server" language="javascript">

Platform.Load("core", "1");
var parentFolderName = "Data Extensions"
var contentType = "dataextension";
var baseFolderID = getFolderIDbyParentName("YOURBASEFOLDERNAMEHERE",parentFolderName, contentType);
Write("<br>baseFolderID: " + baseFolderID);

var startYear = 2023;
var endYear = 2024;
var monthNames = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

try {

  for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {

    Write("<br>year: " + year);

    var yearFolderId = getFolderIDbyParentID(year,baseFolderID,contentType);

    if (yearFolderId == 0) {

      yearFolderId = folderCreate(year, baseFolderID, contentType)
      Write("<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;yearFolderId: " + yearFolderId);

    }

    if (yearFolderId > 0) {

        for (var month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {

            monthFolderName = ("0" + month).slice(-2) + "_" + monthNames[month-1];

            var monthFolderId = getFolderIDbyParentID(monthFolderName,yearFolderId,contentType);
            Write("<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;monthFolderId: " + monthFolderId);

            if (monthFolderId == 0) {

              Write("<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;monthFolderName: " + monthFolderName);
              var newMonthFolderId = folderCreate(monthFolderName, yearFolderId, contentType)
              Write("<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;newMonthFolderId: " + newMonthFolderId);

            } else {
              Write("<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;folder already exists");
            }

        }

    }

  }

} catch (e) {
  Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));
}

function getFolderIDbyParentName(folderName,parentFolderName,contentType) {

  var filter = [];
  var sfp1 = {Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:folderName};
  var sfp2 = {Property:"ContentType",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value: contentType};
  var sfp3 = {Property:"ParentFolder.Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value: parentFolderName};
  filter = {LeftOperand: sfp1, LogicalOperator:"AND", RightOperand: sfp2};
  filter = {LeftOperand: filter, LogicalOperator:"AND", RightOperand: sfp3};
  var folder = Folder.Retrieve(filter)
  return folder[0].ID ? folder[0].ID : 0;

}

function getFolderIDbyParentID(folderName,parentFolderID,contentType) {

  var filter = [];
  var sfp1 = {Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:folderName};
  var sfp2 = {Property:"ContentType",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value: contentType};
  var sfp3 = {Property:"ParentFolder.Id",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value: parentFolderID};
  filter = {LeftOperand: sfp1, LogicalOperator:"AND", RightOperand: sfp2};
  filter = {LeftOperand: filter, LogicalOperator:"AND", RightOperand: sfp3};
  var folder = Folder.Retrieve(filter)
  return folder[0].ID ? folder[0].ID : 0;

}

function folderCreate(folderName, folderParentID, contentType) {

  var folderObj = {
    "Name": folderName,
    "CustomerKey": folderName,
    "Description": "",
    "ContentType": contentType,
    "IsActive": "true",
    "IsEditable": "true",
    "AllowChildren": "true",
    "ParentFolderID": folderParentID
  };

  var status = Folder.Add(folderObj);
  return getFolderIDbyParentID(folderName,folderParentID,contentType);
}

</script>
```

**Output**

```
baseFolderID: 322013
year: 2023
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 01_January
  newMonthFolderId: 338779
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 02_February
  newMonthFolderId: 338780
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 03_March
  newMonthFolderId: 338781
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 04_April
  newMonthFolderId: 338782
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 05_May
  newMonthFolderId: 338783
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 06_June
  newMonthFolderId: 338784
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 07_July
  newMonthFolderId: 338785
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 08_August
  newMonthFolderId: 338786
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 09_September
  newMonthFolderId: 338787
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 10_October
  newMonthFolderId: 338788
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 11_November
  newMonthFolderId: 338789
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 12_December
  newMonthFolderId: 338790
year: 2024
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 01_January
  newMonthFolderId: 338791
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 02_February
  newMonthFolderId: 338792
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 03_March
  newMonthFolderId: 338793
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 04_April
  newMonthFolderId: 338794
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 05_May
  newMonthFolderId: 338795
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 06_June
  newMonthFolderId: 338796
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 07_July
  newMonthFolderId: 338797
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 08_August
  newMonthFolderId: 338798
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 09_September
  newMonthFolderId: 338799
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 10_October
  newMonthFolderId: 338800
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 11_November
  newMonthFolderId: 338801
  monthFolderId: 0
  monthFolderName: 12_December
  newMonthFolderId: 338802
```

Comment: This is super helpful and gives me a solid base to start with - thanks Adam!

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying out the script you posted, but for some reason it's not giving me an output. The script seems to run in SFMC, but it doesn't seem to generate the folders under Data Extension as expected.

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly? I set the base folder to "Promotional".